# Warning: Use of undefined constant - Bring PHP project to 8.2

Tags: php

I have an old big project where many array are define without quotes.

An example is:

```
$a=$row["string1"];
$b=$row['string2'];
$c=$row[string3];
echo "Bye bye";
$var="I am $row['string4']!";
$var="I am $row[string5]!";
$row[string6];
$row[string7
];
$arr[]="I am $row[string8]!";
$arr[]=["message", "I am $row[string8]"];
if (true) {
  echo "Hello [how are you]".
}
$myarr[string9]="bye";
```

I need a regular expression that matches arrays without quotes to include the quotes with the preg_replace() function.

I try with this regex `/(?<=\[)([^'"].*[^'"])(?=\])/g` but it doesn't just select arrays.
https://regex101.com/r/ZRM9Ie/1

If i use `/(?<=\$row\[)([^'"].*[^'"])(?=\])/g` work fine but if the array isn't named $row, it doesn't work

In my example only string3,string5,string6,string7,string8 are in scope and `$row[string3]` will be `$row["string3"]`

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Go with this https://regex101.com/r/DYzFK3/2

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE:
I found this regular expression

```
/(?<arr>\$\w+\[)(\s)(?<var>[^"']+?)(\s)\]/g
```

You can use phpstorm for replacement with this patter of replace

```
${arr}"${var}"]
```

PhpStorm Example:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/AYRjK.png